# How important is having a tracing node?

Tags: gnosis-safe

I'm a newbie about gnosis-safe and I'm trying to get some extra information about tracing and the need to have tracking capabilities.

We have two environments and in both, we haven't this option available, we have an empty value for `ETHEREUM_TRACING_NODE_URL` variable and it works somehow.

We checked against Nginx logs for RPC service for the word `trace_filter` and we haven't resulted.

1. Can we assume that there's not necessary to have this node
   configured?
2. What is the advantage of having this node?

Thanks for the support ;)

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

A tracing node is only required on networks where you want to safe gas (to minimize transaction costs) and therefore use a Safe contract version where the event usage was kept to a minimum.

For older Safe contract versions (before 1.3.0) this was the default. With 1.3.0 a [L2 version](https://github.com/gnosis/safe-contracts/blob/1.3.0-libs.0/contracts/GnosisSafeL2.sol) of the Safe contracts was introduced that makes more extensive use of events. This is described more in the [changelog](https://github.com/gnosis/safe-contracts/blob/1.3.0-libs.0/CHANGELOG.md#add-contract-version-that-emits-safe-tx-information-via-events)

More information can also be found in the Safe transaction service repository [README](https://github.com/gnosis/safe-transaction-service#setup-for-production-event-indexing).

So to answer your questions:

1.) No it is not required if you use the 1.3.0 L2 version of the Safe contracts

2.) This works with all versions of the Safe (even the ones without the events)

Comment: Thanks for illuminating us with your knowledge, it was very clear. Thank you very much, really!